# richfaces calendar get value

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I can't get the value of a bean set from the calendar component of the Richfaces calendar. i'm declaring the calendar like this,

```
<h:form>
    <rich:calendar popup="alse"  value="#{cBean.date1}"
        datePattern="MM/dd/yyyy" style="width:200px;">
    </rich:calendar>
</h:form>
```

then a bean with

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class cBean{
  private Date date1

  public setDate1...
  public getDate1...
}
```

left some stuff of other attributes out, but that's basically it. After I click a button to go to another page, the value is not set to the date i picked in the calendar. What am i missing?

Comment: How are you updating the value?